# Java: Is "new String(oldString)" necessary? (Is String a reference or a value?)

Tags: java, string, object, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am writing a method that processes a string (to extract something):
`public static String myProcessor (String myInput) {...`

I want to have some String object inside this method, that I can apply my transformations on (`workString = workString.replace(...`)

However, I don't want to change the original string (via the reference given to my method, i.e.: 
`myProcessor(originalString)`) - because there may be method calls after my method has been called, which also want to process/extract something **from the original string, before my method call**

I am still learning Java and, according to my book (Deitel & Deitel - "Java How To Program"):
~"primitive types are pass-by-value. Other variable types are for objects and those are pass-by-reference and therefore variable assignment of an object is passing the reference to the same object. A change in the object referenced by one variable can be seen when reading the other variable (if `Object var2 = var1`)"
(This isn't verbatim, just what I understood from it!)

So, I thought I'd try: `String workString = new String(myInput);` and this should create a new String object, using data from `myInput`, but I could manipulate `workString` anyway I want, without worrying I am making changes to an object which is used elsewhere.

IntelliJ suggested that this is redundant, and I can just do: `String workString = myInput`, which got me confused...

Is IntelliJ right here? 
Actually, do I even need to create a local-scope `workString`, or references are "detached" once a variable "arrives" into a method? (i.e.: inside `myProcessor`, `myInput` is no longer holding a reference to the `originalString` from the call for `myProcessor`, but it creates a new String object?

Could you also please mention briefly if your answer is regarding just String objects or all objects?
I have a feeling that perhaps String is somewhere between a Primitive type and an Object type and has special rules applied to it...

Comment: In Java, everything is pass-by-value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: `String` is an object all the way. The only truly special thing about it is that you can create them with a string literal—and that's essentially just "compiler magic". There's also the [string pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings).

Comment: Moreover, `String` is immutable, so there is rarely anything to be gained by copying it. Any manipulation you do to `workString` doesn't change the original string, it creates a new one.

Comment: @Slaw but you can do things like myString=myString.replace("x","y") - I guess replace() has some "detachment" going on inside? I mean, it takes the input, creates a new object, with the transformation, and then returns a reference to the new object?

Comment: @DraxDomax that's not changing the string, it's creating a new one and reassigning the variable.

Comment: As noted by Andy, `String` is immutable. Any method which seems like it's manipulating a string's contents is actually returning a new `String` instance and leaving the original instance alone. That's why you have to use the returned instance.

Comment: I guess the way to look at it, is to understand that, the moment I do any transformation on the myInput variable that comes from the method signature, then whatever I assign the transformation into, will be a local variable, containing a reference to a new object, and therefore, returning that, even if it's still called myInput, will return a reference to a new object? So, I should be fine using myInput internally without worrying about changing data in a difference scope?

Comment: When you do `myString = myString.replace("x","y")` you are creating a _new_ String as has been said, and replacing the reference that myString holds with a reference to that new String; the original string is unchanged. The caller of `myProcessor(originalString)` still sees the original reference to the original String object they passed so is unaffected by any of this.

Comment: I suggest reading the link by @MAnouti in the first comment. In Java, everything is _pass-by-value_. That includes objects and primitives. The nuance with regards to objects is that the "value" being passed is the reference to the object. That's why if you pass a `List` to a method, add an element to it, and then query the list in the caller of the method you'll see the changes; you've modified the object itself. But if that same method were to do `list = new ArrayList<>();` (where `list` is the parameter) that will not affect the caller of the method at all.

Comment: I think I get it now, thanks! Oh... the power of hindsight... My question looks so embarrassing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned by @AndyTurner,
In Java `String` is immutable which means any operation on a `String` doesn't change the *original* `String`.

For instance:

```java
myString = "Hello World"; // literal
myString = myString.replace("o", "-"); // not literal
myString = myString + " !"; // not literal
```

`Hello World` is placed in the String Pool and assigned to variable `myString`.
`Hell- W-rld` is placed in the String Pool and assigned to variable  `myString`.
`Hell- W-rld !` is placed in the String Pool  and assigned to variable  `myString`.

BUT !
As `Hell- W-rld` and `Hell- W-rld !` are not literal ([GC of String literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324143/garbage-collection-of-string-literals)) and no more reachable, they are candidate for Garbage Collection.
In the end only two `String` will be in the pool: `Hello World` and  `!` (the two literals).

*EDIT: "o" and "-" will stay in the pool as they are literals too*

> Could you also please mention briefly if your answer is regarding just String objects or all objects

It depends of the property,
[String is not a Primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473488/is-string-a-primitive-or-an-object-in-android-or-java) but is treated in some regards like one. [Primitives are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037082/are-java-primitives-immutable) and so are `String`s.

To answer your title :

> Is “new String(oldString)” necessary? (Is String a reference or a value?)

It allows to store the value in the String Pool but :

```java
String s1 = "Hi";
String s2 = new String(s1); // Any other operation would assign a new reference as String is immutable
s1 == s2; // false
s1.equals(s2); // true
```

A `String` is passed by reference and `new` assign a new reference (to a same `String` in the pool). Both references are different (`s1` and `s2`) but both points to the same value.

Comment: the extra bits were very interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the [correct Answer by IQbrod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65833435/642706) says, `String` is immutable. So no need to worry about changing the text it contains.

If you did want to alter the container text, rather than using the `String` class, you would use another implementation of the interface [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html).

Here is a diagram I made to give you an overview of the various text related classes, and to help in selecting a class for specific purposes.

[image]